# Show that the step function is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the set V consisting of all functions $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, considered as a vector space
over $\mathbb R$ with the usual definitions of addition and scalar multiplication. Consider
the step functions $f_n : \mathbb R \to \mathbb  R$ defined, for each positive integer $n$, by
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
1  \quad\mathrm{if}\quad  -n<x<n \\ 
0  \quad\mathrm{if}\quad |x|\geq n
\end{cases}$$

How would I show that the set $B = \{f_n \mid n\in N \}$ is linearly independent?

I am even sure how to start.

Comment: For any linear combination of $f_n$'s, there will be a region where only one of them non zero. Proceed by induction after that.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that for any $n$, $$\sum_{k=1}^n c_kf_k=0 $$ implies that $$c_1=c_2=\cdots=c_n=0.$$
For $n=1$, the statement is evident, as $c_1f_1=0$ if and only if $c_1=0$. Now suppose the claim is true for some $n\geqslant 1$. Then if $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}c_kf_k=0, $$ we have $$c_{n+1}f_{n+1} + \sum_{k=1}^nc_kf_k=0. $$
If $c_{n+1}\ne0$, then $c_{n+1}f_{n+1}(n)=c_{n+1}\ne0$, and $$\sum_{k=1}^nc_kf_k(n)=0,$$ a contradiction. Hence $c_{n+1}=0$. From the inductive hypothesis, then, $$c_1=c_2=\cdots=c_n=0,$$ and so the statement is true for any $n$.

Comment: Please fix this.  How did you get that the last summation must hold?

Comment: By the inductive hypothesis..?